Filtering Doctrine join by condition
I have the following two Entities, Dimension and DimensionLang.  Each Dimension may have multiple associated DimensionLang entries.  I am trying to get a list of all dimensions and their corresponding DimensionLang Entities restricted by the language ID:
Dimension Entity:
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ps_ppbs_dimension")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DimensionRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Dimension
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_dimension", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DimensionLang::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="dimension")
     */
    private $dimensionLangs;

    // getters and setters

}

and DimensionLang Entity:
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ps_ppbs_dimension_lang")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DimensionRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class DimensionLang
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Dimension::class, inversedBy="dimensionLangs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_dimension", referencedColumnName="id_dimension", nullable=false)
     */
    private ?Dimension $dimension = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned": true})
     */
    private ?int $idLang = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private string $displayName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512)
     */
    private string $image;

    // Getters and setters
}

And then in my repository I am trying to the following:
    $dimensions = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->join('PrestaShop\Module\ProductPriceBySize\Entity\DimensionLang', 'dl', 'WITH', 'd.id = dl.dimension')
        ->where('dl.idLang = :idLang')
        ->setParameter('idLang', 1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    // Iterate over dimensions
    foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
        echo "Dimension ID: " . $dimension->getId() . "<br>";

        // Iterate over DimensionLang entries
        foreach ($dimension->getDimensionLangs() as $dimensionLang) {
            dump($dimensionLang);
        }
    }

However, when I iterate over the dimension->getDimensionLangs() entries for all the languages the DimensionLang table are returned.  This is confusing because the query contains the necessary condition to filter by id_lang.
How can I get a result filtered by language without filtering in PHP, like one can in plain SQL?
The doctrine version is 2.6
